# Should we change inappropriate nicknames?

Tags: discussion, user-profile, users

To my knowledge (reading documents) there is no regulation to inapproprate nicknames and reporting and enforcement. Recently on I came across this person with the name "poop shitter" and although it may not cause any harm/offence, on many other forum and game sites, they still have regulations regarding inappropriate nicknames.

Comment: The terms of condtions : https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#attribution doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: Report a post or comment of theirs for mod attention and call out what's wrong with their name, we can review their profile from there. It's the only way to alert us to this stuff, you can't report a profile directly

Comment: @Robotnik That's what I am trying to bring up. Should there be a way just to report a certain person, and maybe even have options for "bot" or such -- anyhow this is another question.

Comment: @Robotnik I've also seen that action has been name and he has been renamed to a user#####

Comment: Yup, someone else reported them and another Moderator has actioned it already :-)

Comment: Why can't I earn reputation from meta.. urgh this would have been 100 rep..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The enforcement of appropriate content (on User's Profiles or otherwise) is covered by the [Be Nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) Policy:

> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.
> 2. **Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.** Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help.
> 3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
>    - **Name-calling**. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
>    - **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
>    - **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.
>    - **Harassment and bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

Unfortunately you can't flag/report a profile directly, but if you see something that may run afoul of the above guidelines in someone's username or profile, you should flag a post of theirs for mod attention using a custom reason and call out what's wrong, we'll take a look and action it if appropriate.

Comment: That's what I've been looking for, the "Be nice" policy

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)